# Remotely controlling a java pplication

Tags: java

I made a monitoring application using JAVA , it takes a udp stream carrying tv channels and displays them in one frame.
The application has a lot of buttons and controls , like : disabling channels , mute , choose speaker , snapshots ...

Now the problem is the customer wants to install it on a server but control it from a different computer (security purposes). what i mean is the application has to start and be processed on the server but the display and input has to be on the computer, the GUI needs to be shown on the other computer.

I'm trying to stay away from having to do this manually through socket programming (if possible because) as i said there are so much controls in this .

what would be the best or maybe easiest approach to this ?

thank you

Comment: It would seem to me that ssh-ing into the server would be a better bet...

Comment: that's the problem , it's not allowed to do that ... millitary :/

Comment: oh... Service calls and a web UI written securely?

Comment: Can you use RDP or VNC to remotely view and control the GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [RMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation). You may decouple server-side from the actual controls that you actually use locally, without the need for socket programming. And from a programmatic point of view, you're actually using and calling methods on objects as if they're your own and locally available.

Comment: if i use this , does the server do the processing or the client who called the method ?

Comment: When you're calling a method, the server is the one that actually does the call (executes the code inside the method) and returns the result to you.

Comment: See if this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/overview.html) provides more insight into RMI.

Answer (score 0):

There are remote support applications such as [logmein](http://www.logmein.com/) that allow your customer to see your gui and run it as if they were on the remote machine.